# asp.net mvc transactionscope class

Tags: asp.net-mvc

i want to add transactionscope class in vs 2010. where can i find it? in which namespace. according to msdn there is a system.transaction but there is not? is it extenal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to [add reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wkze6zky(VS.80).aspx) to the `System.Transactions.dll` assembly in your project and the [TransactionScope](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionscope.aspx) class is located in the `System.Transactions` namespace.